# Docker Hub Login for AWS CodeBuild (Docker Hub Limit)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

This is my Current Setup:

1. Gets repository from Bitbucket
2. Builds the docker image using the Amazon Linux 2 AWS managed image
3. Push the image to ECR

I am now sometimes getting the *toomanyrequests* error during the docker build phase. So, now I want to login to my docker hub account and get rid of this issue.

How do I go about logging into docker hub account only for the build phase?
Should I use the buildspec.yml for logging in? But that would conflict with the AWS ecr login, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That article that Hridiago shared is very helpful.

I have also experienced this issue (It occurred after Docker Hub set limits to the number of unathenticated pulls that could be made per day).

If you have used AWS secrets-manager to store your DockerHub username and password (using key/value pair) your buildspec will look like this (note that my secret is stored as /dockerhub/credentials):

```
version: 0.2

env:
  secrets-manager:
    DOCKERHUB_PASS: "/dockerhub/credentials:password"
    DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: "/dockerhub/credentials:username"
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo pre_build step...
      - docker login --username $DOCKERHUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKERHUB_PASS
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
```

You will need to ensure that your code build has the correct permissions to access your secrets-manager as mentioned in the article

Answer (score 3):

Julia Cowper's solution should be the accepted answer.
Here is the same solution for terraform with codebuild.

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "builder" {
  environment = {
    environment_variable {
      type = "SECRETS_MANAGER"
      name = "DOCKERHUB_USER"
      value = "[secret-name]:username"
    }
    environment_variable {
      type = "SECRETS_MANAGER"
      name = "DOCKERHUB_PASS"
      value = "[secret-name]:password"
    }
  }
}
```

and you need you secret to look like

```
{
  "username": [username],
  "password": [password],
}
```

then in the buildspec

```
pre_build:
   commands:
     - echo Logging in to Docker Hub...
     - echo "$DOCKERHUB_PASS" | docker login --username $DOCKERHUB_USER --password-stdin
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS secret manager for using authenticated requests for docker is good way, syntax is as below:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  shell: bash
  secrets-manager:
    DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: DockerHubSecret:dockerhub_username
    DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD: DockerHubSecret:dockerhub_password
  
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo logging in docker hub
      - docker login --username $DOCKERHUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
```

Comment: I have a question. docker login --password $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD then, shell logs couldn't expose secret value? ( I guess that doesn't matter. )

Comment: you can hide the password using echo "pass" | docker login --password-stdin